# Prewarming several images in same model with django-versatileimage

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm successfully using VersatileImage for my django project to prewarm images (i.e. save images at various sizes postsave), but I've come up against a situation where I want my model to have several image fields and I'm not sure how to prewarm them as the code I'm using only seems to allow a reference to a single image field.

models.py

```
class Testimonial(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    image = VersatileImageField('image_testimonial', upload_to=upload_location, validators=[file_size], null=True, blank=True)
    image2 = VersatileImageField('image_testimonial', upload_to=upload_location, validators=[file_size], null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.TextField(default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username    

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Testimonial)
def warm_testimonial_images(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    testimonial_img_warmer = VersatileImageFieldWarmer(
        instance_or_queryset=instance,
        rendition_key_set='image_testimonial',
        image_attr='image'
    )
    num_created, failed_to_create = testimonial_img_warmer.warm()

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Testimonial)
def delete_testimonial_images(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.image.delete_all_created_images()
    instance.image.delete(save=False)
```

This code will only prewarm images that are uploaded to the 'image' file on the model on account of this line:

```
image_attr='image'
```

I'm not sure how to adapt this code to handle image2 as well.

Thanks